# Index of the City sets by category

Tags: sets, theme

I'm running trough bricklink, peeron and brickowl, but I can't find a "good" (I mean 'fitting my idea') index to browse across city sets.

Is there a kind of list like

- vehicle

  - cars
  - trucks
  - planes
- buildings

  - houses

    - 7641
  - police station
  - ...

does anyone of you have knows a such index ?

note: my english is not fluent, so, here are some precisions:
I'm looking for "houses" sets on ebay to complete my son's town streets.
He has a lot of vehicles, but a few buildings

Answer (score 6):

No, but Brickset now provides the facility to enable one to be made. See http://brickset.com/article/12960/tags-a-new-way-to-search-the-database

Answer (score 1):

While there is no explicit "house" tag, I would recommend browsing in Brickset's City theme: http://brickset.com/sets/theme-City

You can refine the search based on year (include only recent, therefore easy to buy sets), tags (building, shop, ...) and subtheme (airport, construction, police, ...).